# How can I build Qt 5.6.1 *.dll files from qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.gz (or later)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, dll

The environment:

- Windows 8.1
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- Build Qt from [qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.gz](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.gz)
- Using jom to build via the NMake Makefiles

Everything builds fine, but the shared library files do not have the *.dll file name extension. They exist, and `dumpbin` recognizes them as dll files, but they are named QtCore, QtGui, ... instead of QtCore.dll, QtGui.dll, ...

Therefore, when I try to build a client project against the Qt I've built, I get CMake configure time errors because the `find_package(Qt)` call can't find any *.dll files.

Why did this change between Qt 5.4.2 and 5.6.1 and is there a fix for it?

I can build Qt 5.4.2 in exactly the same environment I **do** get *.dll files, but I cannot build Qt 5.5.* at all on Windows, and both Qt 5.6.1 and 5.7.0 yield this problem when I build on Windows.

Comment: Last time I've seen this there was a Cygwin installation interfering.

Comment: No cygwin here. Unless the git bash prompt for Windows counts as cygwin.

Comment: Well, it might. Have you tried using a VS command prompt instead?

Comment: I can try from a raw VS command prompt. I have been building from a raw Windows command prompt, including the VS command prompt to set up the environment, and then further adding to the env so the git tools are available in PATH. Other parts of the build (non-Qt) do stuff from git repos and I need to get the hash of the latest commit when building in those sub-trees. I'll give it a try from a raw VS command prompt and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

My root question was: "Why did this change between Qt 5.4.2 and 5.6.1 and is there a fix for it?"

I never did figure out "why?", nor if there was a fix for Qt 5.6.x, or 5.7, or 5.8, or 5.9.

However... we have now updated to using Qt 5.10.1 and all works well again. So whatever it was has, for the time being, gone away.